# Can I implement "select" and "copy" on UILabel when it has a long press just as UITextField (UITextView、UIWebView), and how?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Please give me a hand~ I wanna know how to make UILabel have a system Clipboard(e.g. copy and select) like UITextField (UITextView、UIWebView) when it has a long press, which makes me can copy the text I want. I have read some demo on Github, however, they always only contain copy function, which makes me can't choose the text I want to copy. At present I wanna implement "select" on UILabel but I don't know how to work out. 
  Can I use UITextField without editing function? But once I turn off editing function, there is no system Clipboard when it has a long press. 
  Or if there is a simpler method to work out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're gonna have to implement it yourself. There isn't anything too special about any of the system text views, just read the docs for `UIPasteboard`, specifically around `-[UIPasteboard setString:]`. The rest just comes down to how you want to implement the UI. For that I'd recommend looking into subclassing `UILabel` just to keep everything tidy; `UIMenuController` for showing the callout view; implementing `-canBecomeFirstResponder`, `-canPerformAction:forSender:`, and `-copy:` to customize the callout actions; and `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` for triggering everything.

Comment: It seems there is no shortcut, lazy-man is going to work hard! Okay, thank you!

Comment: I have tried, but it does't work ! Your solution is same to the demo on Github that copy the whole label text, however, I just wanna copy some text of the label instead of the whole.(e.g. label.text = @"hello boy!", and I only need "boy" strings, not the whole strings!)

Comment: What doesn't work? Instead of setting label.text add some attribute like "textIWantCopied" and use that. You are in control of the string you pass to the pasteboard.

Comment: First of all, thank your focus and patient. Maybe you didn't get my idea, I just wanna make a label with a editing pop-menu that includes copy, select, web-search and so on. And now I see the key is the select, which make users can copy the text what they want, just like the "select" of system clipboard . So "textIWantCopied" is unpredictable，it all depends on users use select to choose. Therefore, I don't think it's useful to add some attribute like "textIWantCopied" . At last my question converts  to this : Can I implement "select" method on label like system "select" on textfield, and how?

Comment: If you are talking about drawing a selection rect with resize grabbers, you are best off using a UITextView with isEditable set to NO. This will allow selection without allowing keyboard focus. I am unsure if UITextField will behave similarly or not (I have a hunch it will). To customize the callout you'll still use the first responder / `canPerformAction:withSender:` methods.

Comment: Yeap, UITextView is the best choice instead of UITextFeild. And there is another question, because only by drawing text can I justify alignment automatically, that's why I alaway wanna use UILabel that has a method called "drawTextInRect: ".  Unluckly, I don't konw how to draw text in UITextView, in which method?

Comment: I'm confused, you don't need to do the drawing if you're using UITextView, you just set the string and it draws it. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In order to calculating **UITextView‘s height**, I can't find a better way to calculate it when its text has **line spacing** (Because I have used NSAttributedString to set line spacing ). Thus, I studied a old demo to draw text and calculate height. But at last, I'm shocked with `[textView sizeToFit]` which can set height automatically. Just setting x, y and width, height is arbitrary, then calling  `[textView sizeToFit]`, all is done. These days are Chinese Spring Festival, maybe my head is struck and also on holiday... ...